# How to get position of edge weights in a networkx graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Currently there is a function in [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) library for getting positions of all nodes: [`spring_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html). Quoting from the docs, it returns:

> dict :
> A dictionary of positions keyed by node

And can be used as:

```
G=nx.path_graph(4)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
```

I would like something similar to **access the position of an edge-weight for a weighted graph**. It should return the position of where the number for edge-weight would be placed, preferably at the center of the edge and just above the edge. (By above, I mean "outside" the graph, so for a horizontally-placed square graph's bottom-most edge, it would be just below the edge).

So the question is, is there anything in-built similar to `spring_layout` for achieving this? And if not, how to go about it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nx.draw_edge_labels` which returns a dictionary with edges as keys and `(x, y, label)` as values

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# Create a graph
G = nx.path_graph(10)

# Add 2 egdes with labels
G.add_edge(0, 8, name='n1')
G.add_edge(2, 7, name='n2')

# Get the layout
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# Draw the graph
nx.draw(G, pos=pos)

# Draw the edge labels
edge_labels = nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos)
```

[image].

Now you can see the variables `edge_labels`

```
print(edge_labels)
# {(0, 1): Text(0.436919941201627, -0.2110471432994752, '{}'),
#  (0, 8): Text(0.56941037628304, 0.08059107891826373, "{'name': 'n1'}"),
#  (1, 2): Text(0.12712625526483384, -0.2901338796021985, '{}'),
#  (2, 3): Text(-0.28017240645783603, -0.2947104829441387, '{}'),
#  (2, 7): Text(0.007024254096114596, -0.029867791669433513, "{'name': 'n2'}"),
#  (3, 4): Text(-0.6680363649371021, -0.26708812849092933, '{}'),
#  (4, 5): Text(-0.8016944207643129, -0.0029986274715349814, '{}'),
#  (5, 6): Text(-0.5673817462107436, 0.23808073918504968, '{}'),
#  (6, 7): Text(-0.1465270298295821, 0.23883392944036055, '{}'),
#  (7, 8): Text(0.33035539545007536, 0.2070939421162053, '{}'),
#  (8, 9): Text(0.7914739158501038, 0.2699223242747882, '{}')}
```

Now to get the position of say, edge `(2,7)`, you just need to do

```
print(edge_labels[(2,7)].get_position())
# Output: (0.007024254096114596, -0.029867791669433513)
```

You can read more about the documentation [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels).

If you want to extract the `x,y` coordinates of all the edges, you can try this:

```
edge_label_pos = { k: v.get_position()
                  for k, v in edge_labels.items()}
#{(0, 1): (0.436919941201627, -0.2110471432994752),
# (0, 8): (0.56941037628304, 0.08059107891826373),
# (1, 2): (0.12712625526483384, -0.2901338796021985),
# (2, 3): (-0.28017240645783603, -0.2947104829441387),
# (2, 7): (0.007024254096114596, -0.029867791669433513),
# (3, 4): (-0.6680363649371021, -0.26708812849092933),
# (4, 5): (-0.8016944207643129, -0.0029986274715349814),
# (5, 6): (-0.5673817462107436, 0.23808073918504968),
# (6, 7): (-0.1465270298295821, 0.23883392944036055),
# (7, 8): (0.33035539545007536, 0.2070939421162053),
# (8, 9): (0.7914739158501038, 0.2699223242747882)}
```